# save an editText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an editText (R.id.editText1).
But when i exit the activity and restart it, the text is gone.
So i thought that i make an option menu.

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0, MENU_SAVE, 0, "Save");
    menu.add(1, MENU_GET, 1, "Get");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case MENU_SAVE:
        Here i must save the editText1
        return true;
    case MENU_GET:
        Here i must get the editText1 that i have saved
        return true;
    }

    return false;
```

But i don't now how to save an editText and how to load it.
I hope you can help me, because i'm newbe to android.

Gaauwe

Edit:

I found the answer on my own.
If you have also problems you can go to:
http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/state-persistence/

Gaauwe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how long you want to persist the data and how big the text is. Checkout this page on Android.com

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: So i have:SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putBoolean("silentMode", mSilentMode);

      // Commit the edits!
      editor.commit();                                                But how can i save my editText1,                                           And i have: SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
       boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
       setSilent(silent);                                            How can i load editText1?

Comment: editor.putString("stringIdentifier", stringToBeSaved).commit(); //would save it.

Comment: settings.getString("stringIdentifier", null); //would return it.

Comment: So now its: SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("stringIdentifier", AANTEKENING).commit(); And load is:  SharedPreferences settings1 = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
         settings1.getString("stringIdentifier", null); But When i exit the activity to the homescreen, and i go to the edit activity, and i pres load, there doesn't come any text. Do you now what to do?

Answer (score 2):

Try using a SharedPrefrences to save the value in an edittext.

Answer (score 0):

SharedPrefrences is an easy way to do this.